# Create an automatic popup message box when progressbar is complete

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I have a Progress bar that is launched when a button is clicked. I would like to have a popup message when the progress bar reaches 100%.
Here is the snippet of what I've done:

```
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(TrialWizardPage, self).__init__(parent)

        self.progressBar = QProgressBar(self)
        self.progressBar.setGeometry(10, 250, 610, 20)

        self.btnStart = QPushButton('Begin proccessing', self)
        self.btnStart.move(30, 80)
        self.btnStart.clicked.connect(self.startProgress) 

        self.timer = QBasicTimer()
        self.step = 0

    def startProgress(self):
        if self.timer.isActive():
            self.timer.stop()
            self.btnStart.setText('Begin processing')
        else:
            self.timer.start(100, self)
            self.btnStart.setText('Pause')

    def timerEvent(self, event):
        if self.step >= 100:
            self.timer.stop()
            self.step = 0
            self.btnStart.setText('Restart processing')
            self.label_info.setText("Processing complete")
            self.progressBar(self.clickMethod)
            return

        self.step +=1
        self.progressBar.setValue(self.step)

    def clickMethod(self):
        msg = QMessageBox()
        msg.setIcon(QMessageBox.Information)
        msg.setText("Processing complete!")
        msg.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox.Ok)
```

However, at the end of the progress, I do not get the popup message. Is there anything that I'm missing here?

Comment: The line `self.progressBar(self.clickMethod)` doesn't make sense, just call the function on its own `self.clickMethod()`. Also add `msg.exec()` in order to show the message box.

Comment: @alec that does the trick! thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should use the signal QProgressBar.valueChanged and connect it to a function that compare the current value with the maximum value that the progress bar is set

```
def F_valueChanged(val):
    if val==ui.progressBar.maximum():   #it would be better >= instead of ==
        QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(None,'Info', "Processing complete!",QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Ok) #Replace none with the QWidget you want to center the message box

ui.progressBar.valueChanged.connect(F_valueChanged) #connect signal to function
```